# TypeError: setText(self, str): argument 1 has unexpected type 'tuple'

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, pyqt, pyqt5

I created a code in which, when "load" is clicked, the user will upload a .png image and opencv will perform houghcircle and count the circles.

[image: GUI]

and the count, will be displayed on the textlabel. The circles.shape would result to (1, 99, 3), and I want to display 99, or even the whole (1, 99, 3) on the textlabel.

the problem is, I get this error after uploading the image

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "try.py", line 58, in Browse
>       self.label_2.setText(circles.shape)
>   TypeError: setText(self, str): argument 1 has unexpected type 'tuple'

Here is my code:

```
def Browse(self):
    filter = "Images (*.png)"
    fname, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open Image", "Desktop", filter)
    print(fname)
    self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
    self.scene.addPixmap(QPixmap(fname))
    self.graphicsView_2.setScene(self.scene)

    img = cv2.imread(fname,0)
    cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,5,
                        param1=200,param2=8,minRadius=0,maxRadius=7)

    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
    for i in circles[0,:]:
        # draw the outer circle
        cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),1)
        # draw the center of the circle
        cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),1)
    numberofcells = print(circles.shape)
    self.label_2.setText(circles.shape)
```

any help would be appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: shape return a tuple (height, width, channel), not a str. You can't call setText with a tuple as argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`setText()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#text-prop) expects a string but you are passing it a tuple, a possible solution is:

```
self.label_2.setText(str(circles.shape))
```

Comment: `circles.shape` is tuple, and as @eibersji said, `setText()` expects string. If you want to display it as a string representation of this tuple use `str(circles.shape)` and if you want a second number of that tuple only, use `str(circles.shape[1])`, but converting it to string is necessary because of function expects only string, and thos two methods returns tuple and integer.